# How to make a webApi a Windows service by adding Start, Stop and Restart event handling in .Net 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, .net-6.0

How to make a webApi a Windows service by adding Start, Stop and Restart event handling in .Net 6?
In .Net 5 and before that, I usually make an AppStartup like this:

```
public interface IAppStartup
    {
        Task StartAsync();
        Task StopAsync();
        Task RestartService(IHostedService hostedService);
    }

public class AppStartup : IAppStartup
    {
        private readonly string[] _args;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new();
        private IHost _host;
        private static AppStartup _appStartup;

        private AppStartup(string[] args)
        {
            _args = args;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync()
        {
            try
            {                
                _host = CreateHostBuilder(_args).Build();

                var setting = _host.Services.GetService<AppSettings>();
                if (setting != null)
                {
                    ///
                }

                await _host.RunAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ///
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task StopAsync()
        {
            try
            {                
                await _host.StopAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ///
                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task RestartService(IHostedService hostedService)
        {
            if (hostedService!=null)
            {
                await hostedService.StopAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                await hostedService.StartAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
        }      
    }
```

Now in .Net 6, I am confused because there is no Startup method anymore to call.
Please kindly advise me of any solution you use to add Windows service functionalities into a web API project.

Answer (score 0):

Both .NET 5 and .NET 6 have support for the Windows Service lifetime, which hooks into `Start`/`Stop` for you. So it's essentially just this in your Program.cs:

```
host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(...)
    .Build();

var setting = host.Services.GetService<AppSettings>();
if (setting != null)
{
  ///
}

await host.RunAsync();
```